# How to define the Jacobian matrix for all points of a finite-type k-scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Ravi Vakil's notes 13.2.D asks: "Show that if the Jacobian matrix for X = Spec $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots f_r)$ has corank d at all closed points, then it has corank d at all points. (Hint: the locus where the Jacobian matrix has corank d can be described in terms of vanishing and nonvanishing of certain explicit matrices.)"

But I can't even see how to define the Jacobian matrix for non-closed points. He defines the Jacobian matrix as the $n$ by $r$ matrix such that $a_{ij} = $ the partial derivative of $f_j$ with respect to $x_i.$ If p is a closed point, then this makes sense; this partial derivative can be evaluated at p. But I don't see how he is defining the Jacobian matrix for all points, not just closed points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the Jacobian matrix doesn't make any reference to *any* points, closed or not.  It is just the matrix $a_{ij}$ of partial derivatives of the $f_j$ w.r.t. the $x_i$.  It is an $r\times n$ matrix with entries in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$,
and you consider its image in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak p$, for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ containing $(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$ (or for any prime ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ at all, for that matter, but we only care about its image modulo the points of $X$, which are those $\mathfrak p$ containing $(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$), which is a matrix with entries in the residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$.  Now you can talk about its corank.  This is what is meant by the corank of the Jacobian matrix at the point $\mathfrak p$.